# Changing the VB6 InputBox() caption to english

Tags: vb6

I have an input box.

This input box appear with frensh caption ("Ok" and "Annuler") instead of ("Ok" and "Cancel")

How to allow showing the english version?

The application is build with an XP frensh version.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would expect this to vary based on the locale of the end-user's system, not the version of VB6 with which you're compiling it. Have you tried running your program on a system with the locale set to (one of the various choices for) English?

Comment: I tested with language = English in the regional options, but it's the same issue.

Comment: Then try to compile with english VB6?

Comment: I suspect you would have to supply the local version of MsVbVm60.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputBox()` function is implemented in the VB6 runtime DLL and as such is subject to it's localisation (along with error message text). You should ensure that you're distributing the official (language neutral) `msvbvm60.dll` from the [Service pack 6 runtime package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417).

Comment: +1 From memory the VB6 runtime also looks for some separate resource DLLs providing translations into other languages. If they are present (e.g. installed into Windows System by another package) this can cause  the runtime to localise into another language. AFAICR there is a knowledge base article about this, but no time to dig it out now

Comment: @MarkJ: I thought it only did that if the current locale was set to one that was available? The OP said it was in english.

Comment: It can also happen if you compile with a localised version of VB6, see my (new) answer. I have my notes handy this time :)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the EXE was built with a localised version of VB6.

> If you compile any localized application on a given language version
>   of Visual Basic, the application .exe, .dll, and .ocx files will still
>   call the run-time resources corresponding to the language of the
>   compiler.

There are some possible fixes in [Microsoft KB article 236404](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236404)